# How do I install boto?

Tags: python, installation, boto

So that I am able to work with it within my python scripts?

Comment: What was wrong with http://code.google.com/p/boto/wiki/RunningFromSubversion?  This seems perfectly clear.  What didn't you like?  What confused you?

Comment: On CentOS: yum install python-boto

Answer (score 73):

1. If necessary, install pip:

   `sudo apt-get install python-pip`
2. Then install boto:

   `pip install -U boto`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-pip` if using ubuntu

Comment: What does -U stands for?

Comment: @TroodoN-Mike the `-U` is short for `--upgrade` which tells pip to "Upgrade all specified packages to the newest available version".  So if boto is already installed, it will update it to the latest version.

Answer (score 36):

Installing Boto depends on the Operating system. 
For e.g in Ubuntu you can use the aptitude command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-boto
```

Or you can download the boto code from their site and move into the unzipped directory to run

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Using apt-get gave me an old version of boto.  For the lastest version, this works: `git clone https://github.com/boto/boto.git; cd boto; sudo python setup.py install`

Comment: Nowadays pip is the appropriate way of doing this. See the pip answer below.

Answer (score 15):

```
$ easy_install boto
```

Edit: pip is now by far the preferred way to install packages

Answer (score 5):

switch to the `boto-*` directory and type `python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 2):

1. install pip: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html
2. insatll boto: https://github.com/boto/boto

   $ git clone git://github.com/boto/boto.git
   $ cd boto
   $ python setup.py install

Answer (score 1):

Best way to install boto in my opinion is to use:

```
pip install boto-1.6
```

This ensures you'll have the boto glacier code.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but you probably shouldn't specify this version now that there's newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have boto installed in one python version and then install a higher python version, boto is not found by the new version of python.

For example, I had python2.7 and then installed python3.5 (keeping both). My script under python3.5 could not find boto. Doing "`pip install boto`" told me that boto was already installed in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.

So I did

```
pip install --target /usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages boto
```

This allowed my script under python3.5 to find boto.

Answer (score 1):

While trying out the

```
pip install boto
```

command, I encounter the error

```
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

To resolve this, issue another command to handle the setuptools using curl

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py | python
```

After doing that, the following command will work perfectly.

```
pip install boto
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a mac, by far the simplest way to install is to use `easy_install`

```
sudo easy_install boto3
```